# dplyr tidyr based subsetting not working in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following data frame created in R

```
 df<-data.frame("X_F"=c(5,10,20,200, 5,10,15,25,30,60,200, NA), 
 "X_A"=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA),"Y_F"=c(5,20,200, NA, 5,12,16,25,100, NA, 
  NA, NA), "Y_A"=c(1,2,3,NA, 1,2,3,4,5,NA, NA, NA), "Z_F"=c(5,10,20,100, 
  4,12,1,7,30,100,200, 250), 'Z_A'=c(1,2,3,4,1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10), "ID"=c("A", 
  "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B",  "B","B","B", "B", "B"))
```

The data frame has differing entries across rows and looks as follows

```
     X_F X_A Y_F Y_A Z_F Z_A ID
 1    5   1   5   1   5   1  A
 2   10   2  20   2  10   2  A
 3   20   3 200   3  20   3  A
 4  200   4  NA  NA 100   4  A
 5    5   1   5   1   4   1  B
 6   10   2  12   2  12   3  B
 7   15   3  16   3   1   4  B
 8   25   4  25   4   7   5  B
 9   30   5 100   5  30   6  B
 10  60   6  NA  NA 100   7  B
 11 200   7  NA  NA 200   9  B
 12  NA  NA  NA  NA 250  10  B
```

next I have created a new column called SF that includes all values in X_F, Y_F Z_F as a sequence separated by one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


  df=df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(SF=pmax(X_F,Y_F,Z_F,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  complete(SF=full_seq(SF,1))
```

Next I have created the following columns

```
df[c("X_F2", "Y_F2", "Z_F2") ]<-df$SF
df[c("X_A2", "Y_A2", "Z_A2")]<-NA
```

The following code should transfer values in X_A to X_A2 based on the values in X_F being equal to X_F2.

```
  df<-df%>%group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(X_A2, case_when(X_F2==X_F~X_A))%>%
  mutate(Y_A2, case_when(Y_F2==Y_F~Y_A))%>%
  mutate(Z_A2, case_when(Z_F2==Z_F~Z_A))
```

I am not getting the expected result

The expected result should be as follows

```
 head(data.frame(df$`case_when(X_F2 == X_F ~ X_A)`, df$X_F2),10)

   df..case_when.X_F2....X_F...X_A.. df.X_F2
                               1       5
                              NA       6
                              NA       7
                              NA       8
                              NA       9
                              2       10
                              NA      11
                              NA      12
                              NA      13
                              NA      14
```

However I am getting the following output

```
df..case_when.X_F2....X_F...X_A.. df.X_F2
                              1       5
                             NA       6
                             NA       7
                             NA       8
                             NA       9
                             NA      10
                             NA      11
                             NA      12
                             NA      13
                             NA      14
```

I request someone to take a look. have also tried else if but that clearly doesnt work

Comment: Can you explain **what** you are trying to do rather than **how** you are trying to do it?

Comment: Am trying to expand the dataframe based on SF column and ID. This for ID A, X_F2 should be between the minimum value of SF and the maximum value of SF separated by a step of 1. X_A2 should take values based on X_A such that where X_F2 equals X_F, the corresponding X_A value is placed in X_A2 .

Comment: It sounds like your first code section might not be doing what you expect. At that point, rows 2-15 are NA in every column but ID and SF, which explains why subsequent steps produce NAs in those rows.

Comment: The first section is to create an expanded dataframe based on ID, SF columns.

Comment: The rest is similar to a lookup. look up X_F2 and X_F and return X_A2 where X_F2 equals X_F1

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs Please put the additional information in your question (not in comments), i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56591913/edit